# URL subfolders for multi-language Store Views in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, multistore, store-view, multidomain

I have many shops in many languages and plan to migrate to **magento 2**, so i need to do something like this.

- shop1.com/en/
- shop1.com/fr_fr/
- shop2.com/en/
- shop2.com/it_it/

**I do not want** to use "Store Code to Urls" because I have many store codes and they are build like this "shop1_fr_fr" so look dirty in the url.

I already spent a lot of time reading many topics here and there but i am still not able to make it working, answers are for magento1 or incomplete or i am stupid.

I have ssh access so i can do whatever it require to do (symlinks, update index.php or .htaccess, etc).

If someone can give help.